# Compiling Boost on solaris cc v5.8

Tags: c++, solaris-10, cc

I am trying to build Boost on a solaris system

```
/tmp/boost_1_58_0> cc -V
cc: Sun C 5.8 2005/10/13
usage: cc [ options] files.  Use 'cc -flags' for details
```

I checked on some of sites. On one of the sites I have, 5.10 has been built with a Sun C compiler with `stlport4`, but I don't see any steps to do the same. Between the compiler, I am using v5.8. I do not mind building older versions of boost.

One thing to note is that mine is a production system, so it is not possible to install whatever I want to.

Comment: Which parts of boost do you need? If you only need header only parts of boost you do not even have to build boost it self, just the code using boost.

Comment: i am looking primarily at thread , chrono, program options, DI,regex , serialization and few others. I can try to minimize my usage but will it all be enough to include the headers? I will give it a try, i hope you will be with me till this is resolved. :)

Comment: Error: complex expression not allowed in dependent template argument expression.this is the error i get while using chrono. I guess i should try older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below link, it is better you move to v5.9 or there is no way you can get it build/supported(even for header only libraries) without wasting your time.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/cccompare-137792.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with 5.9:  "complex expression not allowed in dependent template argument expression."

I resolved that issue with the compiler flag: -Qoption ccfe -complextmplexp